# React Router Dom V6 Conditional Check

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to do a conditional check on whether the user is logged in, and if they try to access login / register, then it should redirect them to the Home page.

The way I tried doing this was by doing the following:

```
const App = () => {
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user.currentUser);

  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/products" element={<ProductList />} />
        <Route path="/products/:category" element={<ProductList />} />
        <Route path="/product/:id" element={<Product />} />
        <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart />} />

        <Route path="/register" element={user ? <Home /> : <Register />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={user ? <Home /> : <Login />} />
        
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  )
};
```

It works in the sense that the user will be redirected to the Home component, however the URL still shows `localhost:3000/login` even if they don't have to login. Do I need to be using something else?

Answer (score 1):

In v5 you would use `<Redirect />` in order to redirect the url from `localhost:3000/login` to `localhost:3000/` and for the life of me, I couldn't figure out why it wouldn't work. In v6 it is now `<Navigate />` with the additional use of the `useNavigate` hook. You'll have to add a replace prop in order to replace the the page.

Instead of what you currently have:

```
<Route path="/register" element={
   user ? <Home /> : <Register />
} />
<Route path="/login" element={
   user ? <Home /> : <Login />
} />
```

try:

```
<Route path="/register" element={
   user ? <Navigate replace to="/" /> : <Register />
} />
<Route path="/login" element={
   user ? <Navigate replace to="/" /> : <Login />
} />
```

This worked for me, but the [example](https://reactrouterdotcom.fly.dev/docs/en/v6/examples/auth) in the docs uses a state prop, rendering the `<Naviagation />` component inside of an if statement. You can try refactoring your code according to the example and see if that works as well.

[React Router - Upgrading from v5 to v6](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#what-did-we-miss)
[See this article on v6 changes as well](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/react-router-v6-what-changed-and-upgrading-guide-part-two/).